# Results from string search not printing to console as expected

Tags: c, file

So I have this code which I was working on. The goal is to search for a string in a file and when that string is found it would return the corresponding values in that section of the file. So this is the file in question that is being searched: [image]

So if it finds "**AJ**" then it would return all the values right up to "22550" and if it finds "**TS**" then it prints everything after "**TS**" and after "60500." This is my code in question:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
   char *name;
   char *code;
   int grpsize;
   char route;
   char *package;
   //float fee;
   float tcost;
   float fcost;
} bookingrecord;

int main() {
FILE *fptr;
bookingrecord bookingrec;
char book_code[5];
printf("\n Please enter the code that corressponds to your record: ");
scanf("%s", book_code);
fptr = fopen("bookingdata", "r");
if (fptr == NULL) {
    printf ("\nSorry we didn't find your file.");
    exit (1);
}
ssize_t read;
char * line = NULL;
size_t len = 0;
int count = 0;
int found = 0;
while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fptr)) != -1) {
    if (count == 0) {
        bookingrec.code = line;
        //printf("%s %s",bookingrec.code,book_code);
        if (strcmp(bookingrec.code, book_code) == 0) {
            found = 1;
        }
    } else if (count == 1 && found == 1) {
        bookingrec.grpsize = line;
    } else if (count == 2 && found == 1) {
        bookingrec.route = line;
    } else if (count == 3 && found == 1) {
        bookingrec.fcost = strtof(line, NULL);
    } else if (count == 4 && found == 1) {
        bookingrec.name = line;
    } else if (count == 5 && found == 1) {
        bookingrec.package = line;
    } else if (count == 6 && found == 1) {
        bookingrec.tcost = strtof(line, NULL);
    }
    count = count + 1;
    if(strlen(line) == 0) {
        count = 0;
    }
}
if (found == 1) {
    printf("\n We have found your file");
    printf("\n %s", bookingrec.code);
    printf("\n %s", bookingrec.name);
    printf("\n %d", bookingrec.grpsize);
    printf("\n %s", bookingrec.route);
    printf("\n %c", bookingrec.package);
    printf("\n %.2f", bookingrec.tcost);
    printf("\n %.2f", bookingrec.fcost);
}
fclose(fptr);
return 0;
}
```

The problem is that it only gives me this as the result:

[image]

So it finds the file okay but nothing happens so I uncomment a `printf` which I added to troubleshoot a bit right above my `strcmp` and get this when I enter for eg. "**AJ**":

[image]

I try another of the two character string. "**SH**" in this case and get this:

[image]

So it seems as if it is accepting any of the codes but prints the first line twice? But also discards everything else. I am a bit stumped as to what is happening. Any ideas?

Update:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
 char *name;
char *code;
int grpsize;
char *route;
char *package;
//float fee;
float tcost;
float fcost;
} bookingrecord;

int main() {
FILE *fptr;
bookingrecord bookingrec;
char book_code[5];
printf("\n Please enter the code that corressponds to your record: ");
scanf("%s", book_code);
fptr = fopen("bookingdata", "r");
if (fptr == NULL) {
    printf ("\nSorry we didn't find your file.");
    exit (1);
}
ssize_t read;
char * line = NULL;
size_t len = 0;
int count = 0;
int found = 0;
while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fptr)) != -1) {

line[strcspn(line, "\r\n")] = 0; //trims getLine
//printf("line is %s, count is %d \n", line, count);//debugging

    if (count == 0) {

        bookingrec.code = strdup(line);

        if (strcmp(bookingrec.code, book_code) == 0) {
            found = 1;
        }
    } else if (count == 1 && found == 1) {
        char *tmp;
        bookingrec.grpsize = strtol(strdup(line), NULL, 10);
    } else if (count == 2 && found == 1) {
        bookingrec.route = strdup(line);
    } else if (count == 3 && found == 1) {
        bookingrec.fcost = strtof(strdup(line), NULL);
    } else if (count == 4 && found == 1) {
        bookingrec.name = strdup(line);
    } else if (count == 5 && found == 1) {
        bookingrec.package = strdup(line);
    } else if (count == 6 && found == 1) {
        bookingrec.tcost = strtof(strdup(line), NULL);
    }
    count = count + 1;

    if (found == 1 && count == 7){

    break;
    }
    if(strlen(line) == 0) {
        count = 0;
    }


}
if (found == 1) {
    printf("\n We have found your file");
    printf("\n %s", bookingrec.code);
    printf("\n %s", bookingrec.name);
    printf("\n %d", bookingrec.grpsize);
    printf("\n %s", bookingrec.route);
    printf("\n %s", bookingrec.package);
    printf("\n %.2f", bookingrec.tcost);
    printf("\n %.2f", bookingrec.fcost);
}
fclose(fptr);
return 0;
}
```

Updated screens after edits:

[image]

Comment: The output gives you a very clear clue. Did you not ask yourself why the second code is printed on a new line whereas your `printf` does not have a newline in its format string? It means `bookingrec.code` contains a trailing newline character which of course will not match `book_code` that does not have a newline.

Comment: Then you would ask yourself, how did that happen? And to answer that you would read the [getline manual](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html): "*The buffer is null-terminated and includes the newline character*".

Comment: @kaylum I see, trimming could solve it?

Comment: Try it and find out

Comment: It doesn't but still comes back blank. I attempted adding this: `line[strcspn(line, "\r\n")] = 0;` but it does remove the new line but no content on the screen @kaylum

Comment: (1) Your program crashes when it wants to print the uninitialized `bookingrec.route`. (2) The `grpsize` and `route` are not strings. You must parse them to get `int` and `char` values, for example with `atoi`. (3) You assign `line` directly, which means that all string data is a reference the same string, whose content changes with each call to `getline`. When you print, all strings will be the last line read. If you want to save strings permanently, you must make copies, for example with the non-standard but widely available `strdup`.

Comment: @MOehm I made some updates and I think it's okay now. My issue now is the results. See update please

Comment: @MOehm resolved based on your comments. I can accept your answer once you post it

Comment: Glad to hear it's solved. I don't have time right now to write a proper answer.

Comment: Okay whenever you do I'll accept it. Thanks